# Error message IE7 "page contains secure and nonsecure items"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, security, https

my mvc3 application runs on an IIS7 with https encryption. Works fine with every browser, except IE7. Browsing the Application causes on every site a warning message ""page contains secure and nonsecure items"
I've traced the traffic with fiddler and wireshark, all connections, ajax requests, assets, files are loaded via https.
The generated html source code is exactly the same. (compared with and without the nonsecure items)
There are no hardcoded "http://" links in the whole project solutuion.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a discussion of this specific issue [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/rchartier/archive/2008/03/12/ie7-this-page-contains-both-secure-and-nonsecure-items.aspx). Not sure if it your particular problem but it appears IE 7 has an issue when you are manipulating a DOM element, and are setting its style/background property to a incomplete URL.

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/336
fixed the problem.